# Projects run with Eclipse but won't run with Android Studio

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio

I imported a working app from Eclipse to Android Studio (AS) 1.0.2.  I unchecked
- replace jars with dependencies when possible
- replace library sources with dependencies when possible
- create Gradle-style module names
(I've also tried this import with all three checked)

This app uses Google Maps V2 but I kept maps.jar (from V1) around because I have a lot of code that uses the GeoPoint class and I didn't want to rewrite that code.  The project compiles fine in AS and the GeoPoint Class is recognized at compile time.

At run time however, the following exception is thrown upon the first reference of the GeoPoint class:
NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/maps/GeoPoint.

EDIT: After changing the dependency to 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87' I no longer get the noClassDefFound error when running with an actual device.  But I still get it in the emulator.  It is possible this was the case before changing the dependecny.  Could running in the emulator possibly cause a noClassDefFound Error??

I don't recall ever having this happen in Eclipse: if something is recognized at compile time it was always recognized at run time too.
What could possibly cause the GeoPoint class not to be found at run time when compiled in AS but to be found at run time when compiled in Eclipse.

If I can't solve this I'm going to have to stick with Eclipse and I didn't want to do that.  Could it be a bug in AS??

The following  picture shows the project in AS showing the GeoPoint class and the module buile.gradle

[image: mttTrial project]

For a better picture : https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/39662979/AS.png

Comment: Try replacing `compile project(':googleplayservices_lib')` with `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'` (or, better yet, `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:6.5.87'`, for a smaller app). These will require that you have the "Google Repository" installed via your SDK Manager. [Here are the instructions](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html) for adding stuff from Google Play Services, like Maps V2, to Android Studio.

Comment: CommonsWare, with that change it won't even compile as it can't find LocationClient.  I find you explaining this issue on Dec 19 to another poster saying it was depreciated and removed (thank you Google - Grrrrr).  So now I apparently have to change my code in all my apps I bring over to AS.  Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: "with that change it won't even compile as it can't find LocationClient" -- that's not part of Google Maps, and as noted it is gone entirely at this point. "So now I apparently have to change my code in all my apps I bring over to AS" -- `LocationClient` being removed has nothing to do with Android Studio. In my book (which, IIRC, you have), I have a chapter on the fused location provider that shows how the new, not-well-documented replacement for `LocationClient` works.

Comment: I'm reading that. on pp2188 you say we can choose to fall back to the traditional LocationManager solution.  How can we do that if it's gone.

Comment: `LocationManager` is not gone. `LocationClient` is gone. `LocationManager` is part of the Android SDK.

Comment: the LocationClient thing was a diversion - I don't need it.  After applying your first suggestion (6.5.87) the project only gets the noClassDefFoundError in the emulator.  It runs fine on my device!?

Comment: Unless the emulator is one built with a "Google APIs" image, it will not have Play Services.